# Unable to retrieve from and Update entities of a datastore table

Tags: c#, .net, google-app-engine, nosql, datastore

I am new to Google Cloud Datastore (NoSQL db). I am developing a web application in C# for which I have successfully configured authentication for google Datastore API by setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

I am also able to insert data (entities) in the Datastore kind (I think "kind" refers to tables in Google). However, I am unable to retrieve entities based on retrieval, for example, I want to retrieve entities from Datastore, from a kind named "Task" where a column named "word" has the word "hello" in it.

I would also like to know whether I can keep a column which has a datatype of "string" as key column (like a primary key column in SQL database tables). I also need help as to how I can update a column/property for a particular entity.

```
                string projectId = "xyz";
                DatastoreDb db = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId);
                Query query = new Query("Task")
                {
                    Filter = Filter.Equal("word", "hello")

                };

                DatastoreQueryResults  dres = db.RunQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a kind in Cloud Datastore is indeed the equivalent of a table in SQL. Apart from that, each entity has a unique identifier which includes a key name string and a numeric ID (integer).

If you want to retrieve a particular entity, you can use the `Lookup` [function](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity) based on the key of that entity, like this:

```
Entity task = _db.Lookup(_sampleTask.Key);
```

This also applies if you want to retrieve multiple entities:

```
var keys = new Key[] { _keyFactory.CreateKey(1), _keyFactory.CreateKey(2) };
var tasks = _db.Lookup(keys[0], keys[1]);
```

For updating a particular entity, you can modify its properties and then store it using the same key it had before:

```
_sampleTask["priority"] = 5;
_db.Update(_sampleTask);
```

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) can be quite useful to understand how to use Cloud Datastore with .NET and C#. It includes a tutorial for building a bookshelf based in Datastore and deploying it in App Engine.

As for what to use as a key, Datastore uses an ancestor structure, just like a file system directory. One entity can be set as the child of another, that becomes its parent, and this can continue until a full structure is created with ancestors and children.

This is an example of a key from an entity which has ancestors:

```
[User:alice, TaskList:default, Task:sampleTask]
```

This is the key of a root entity, which has no parents:

```
[User:alice]
```

For more info about the ancestor paths, check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths).

Answer (score 0):

In GCP Web Console, you can run queries directly in sql, from there you can do a quick test if the query is returning expected results.

Datastore requires indexes to be crated before you can query on them, from web console when you run the query, you will know more about it.

If you see results on web console, but not able to retrieve when queries programmatically, you can check GCP logs for any exceptions to debug the issue.